# PNG file won't display in ImageView if source is set programatically

Tags: android

I have a png file in my res/drawable-ldpi folder. I'm working in Eclipse with the emulator, but I've tried this on my 2.2.1 Android phone and I get the same behavior.  I have an ImageView and I want to set the src programatically, based on a database call.  If I just put

```
src="@drawable.norusdpyr"
```

in the Activity's XML file, the file displays fine.  BUT, if I put

```
String imageresource = "R.drawable." + parsedData[4].toString();
chart.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageresource));
```

where parsedData[4].toString() = "nor_usdpyr" I don't see anything.  I've also tried

```
String imageresource = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/R.drawable." + parsedData[4].toString();
chart.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageresource));
```

and

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/drawable/" + parsedData[4].toString());
chart.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromStream(is, ""));
```

and

```
String imageresource = "R.drawable." + parsedData[4].toString();   
File file = new File(imageresource);
chart.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath()));
```

and

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
int ResID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageresource, "drawable", "com.KnitCard.project");
chart.setImageResource(ResID);
```

finally,

```
chart.setImageURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/R.drawable.nor_usdpyr"));
```

doesn't work.

None of these work.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this shouldn't be working:

```
src="@drawable.norusdpyr"
```

The correct way is:

```
android:src="@drawable/norusdpyr"
```

Second, those string *ids* that you use in XML are only valid in XML. When the resources are built, all those strings are replaced by their respective *integer* values. Ideally, you won't need to load a package resource from a string name. But if you do, you can look for the field with such name, get the *integral* value it holds, and call `setImageResource`. You were quite close with this version:

```
int ResID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageresource, "drawable", "com.KnitCard.project");
chart.setImageResource(ResID);
```

except that `imageResource` should have been `parsedData[4].toString()` with no `R.drawable.` prefix. You can use `context.getPackageName()` instead of hardcoding your package name.

Comment: src="@drawable.norusdpyr" was a typo on my part. At any rate, your answer works. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the `setImageDrawable()` method to work directly with the resource:

```
myImageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myPngFileName));
```

this will avoid the process of getting the ResID and then using it for access

Comment: Thanks Ben, I improved it now.